# How change url local repository without root folder in POM.xml

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have an issue regarding my maven project. In my pom.xml file I added repositories on my project but for now the link of the repository is static. My question is how change the url path become without using my root folder so when other people pull my project they mustn't change the path first

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///D:/Coding-an/eclipse-workspace/TK_Rama_Automation/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

My expected condition should be like this, but I don't know how to implement it:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repo</id>
        <url>file:///../TK_Rama_Automation/repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: specifyng it with a property is not suitable for you? Calling mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=../[path] should work

Comment: @RobertoBenazzato could you give a reference ?

Answer (score 0):

as more complete answer to your question you have two way to achive what you want:

1. you can specify your repo by using a system property, i.e run `mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=../TK_Rama_Automation/repository`
2. specifing it directaly in your settings section you have to put the tag localRepository, check it out in the official page for [maven configuration](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html)

   <settings> 
    ...
   <localRepository>../TK_Rama_Automation/repository</localRepository>
   ...
   </settings>